# Javascript is not working for element having two classes

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html5-history

I am using Bootstrap `list-group` and there are two classes for list items. I am using JavaScript and it works fine when I have only one class `video`, but it doesn't work when I add `list-group-item` class.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="list-group list-special">
        <a class="video list-group-item  active" href="M0mx8S05v60"><span class="badge">8:56</span>Lec 1: What is Signal?</a>
        <a class="video list-group-item" href="F5h3z8p9dPg"><span class="badge">9:35</span>Lec 2: What is an Analog Signal?</a>
        <a class="video list-group-item" href="jRL9ag3riJY"><span class="badge">8:48</span>Lec 3: What is Digital Signal?</a>
        <a class="video list-group-item" href="izBaDRyqnBk"><span class="badge">5:13</span>Lec 4: Need of Digital Signal</a>
        <a class="video list-group-item " href="2xXErGeeb_Q"><span class="badge">6:42</span>Lec 5: Inroduction to Digital Electronics</a>
        <a class="video list-group-item" href="RF9I6UzI4Rc"><span class="badge">9:41</span>Lec 6: Switch and Bits Intuition</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var onVideoLinkClick = function(e){
            if( e.target.tagName == 'A' && e.target.classList.contains('video')) {
                var videoID = e.target.getAttribute('href');
                history.pushState(
                    {videoID: videoID},
                    e.target.innerText,
                    'video-'+videoID)

                changeVideo(videoID)

                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        var changeVideo = function(videoID){
            var src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoID;
            document.getElementById("videoFrame").src = src;
        }

        var onUrlChange = function(e){
            changeVideo(e.state.videoID)
        }

        window.addEventListener('click', onVideoLinkClick);
        window.onpopstate = onUrlChange;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not simply put the full url within the href attribute?

Comment: Note that *innerText* is a proprietary IE property that is not supported by all browsers in use.

Comment: I'm suspicious of that `.contains()` function, could you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes ?

Comment: @JasonSperske—no, the poster means the DOM [*Element.classList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (links to specifications are provided in the article).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it seems fine, but it won't work when you click on the `<span class="badge">` tag as it will not pass the condition `e.target.tagName == 'A'`

The solution is to add the event listener to the `video` elements only and not to the `window`, I made this working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prh6vfza/

I also suggest you use jquery to attach events

Answer (score 0):

Why make so complex! You can directly get anchor tags with video class and attach event listener to it. By this you can avoid the condition to check if the target is `a`
JS

```
 // Get all anchor tags with video class

   var allAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('video');

  // Use [].slice.apply(cards) to convert the cards NodeList into an array
  // Iterate over the cards array with a .forEach

  [].slice.apply(allAnchorTags).forEach(function(aTags,index){
     // Attach eventlistener to it

            aTags.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                changeVideo(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
                },false)
            })

      function changeVideo(videoId){
             alert(videoId)
             var src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoID;
                document.getElementById("videoFrame").src = src;
             }
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/dvujo0hm/)

**NOTE:** Could not understand this part.So didnt included in demo. Seems it is an array and want to push element into it. Please take care of all closing braces

```
history.pushState(
                    {videoID: videoID},
                    e.target.innerText,
                    'video-'+videoID)

                changeVideo(videoID)

                e.preventDefault();
            }
```